# Hadoop setting fsPermission recursively to dir using Java

Tags: java, hadoop, hdfs

I have test program which loads files into hdfs at this path `user/user1/data/app/type/file.gz` Now this test program runs multiple times by multiple users. So I want to set file permission to rwx so that anyone can delete this file. I have the following code

```
fs.setPermission(new Path("user/user1/data"),new FsPermission(FsAction.ALL,FsAction.ALL,FsAction.ALL))
```

Above line gives `drwxrwxrwx` to all dirs but for the file.gz it gives permission as `-rw-r--r--` why so? Because of this reason another user apart from me not able to delete this file through test program. I can delete file through test program because I have full permission.

I am new to Hadoop.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using FsShell APIs solved my dir permission problem. It may be not be optimal way but since I am solving it for test code it should be fine.

```
      FsShell shell=new FsShell(conf);
      try {
        shell.run(new String[]{"-chmod","-R","777","user/usr1/data"});
      }
     catch (  Exception e) {
        LOG.error("Couldnt change the file permissions ",e);
        throw new IOException(e);
      }
```

Answer (score 1):

I think `Hadoop` doesn't provide a java API to provide permission recursively in the version you are using. The code is actually giving permission to the dir `user/user1/data` and nothing else. You should better use `FileSystem.listStatus(Path f)` method to list down all files in the directory and use `Filsystem.setPermission` to them individually. It's working currently on my 2.0.5-alpha-gphd-2.1.0.0 cluster.

However from `Hadoop 2.2.0` onward a new constructor

[`FsPermission(FsAction u, FsAction g, FsAction o, boolean sb)`](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.2.0/api/org/apache/hadoop/fs/permission/FsPermission.html#FsPermission(org.apache.hadoop.fs.permission.FsAction,%20org.apache.hadoop.fs.permission.FsAction,%20org.apache.hadoop.fs.permission.FsAction,%20boolean))

is being provided. The boolean field may be the recursive flag you wanted. But the documentation(including param name) is too poor to infer something concrete.

Also have a look at [Why does "hadoop fs -mkdir" fail with Permission Denied?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22676593/hadoop-fs-mkdir-permission-denied) although your sitaution may be different. (in my case `dfs.permissions.enabled` is still true).

Comment: For reference, the sb parameter sets the sticky bit; it is not a recursive flag.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote this in scala but I think you could easily adapt it:

```
def changeUserGroup(user:String,fs:FileSystem, path: Path): Boolean ={
  val changedPermission = new FsPermission(FsAction.ALL,FsAction.ALL,FsAction.ALL, true)
  val fileList = fs.listFiles(path, true)
  while (fileList.hasNext()) {
    fs.setPermission(fileList.next().getPath(),changedPermission)
  }
    return true
  }
```

You will also have to add a logic for the error handling, I am always returning true.